# Change return path nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to get file downloading in the local Telegram Bot API work. I found an example on github how to do it with nginx: https://github.com/aiogram/telegram-bot-api/tree/master/example. It's working perfectly with relative paths (e.g documents/file_0.txt). But I need to request file via full path (e.g. /var/lib/telegram-bot-api/bot-token/documents/file_0.txt). When I try to do it, nginx is looking for /var/lib/telegram-bot-api/full path and throws 404. What do I need to change here to fix it? I'm a complete noob in nginx. Here's the config:

````
log_format token_filter '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                        '"$sanitized_request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

upstream telegram-bot-api {
    server api:8081;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    client_body_buffer_size 30M;
    keepalive_timeout 0;
    
    set $sanitized_request $request;
    if ( $sanitized_request ~ (\w+)\s(\/bot\d+):[-\w]+\/(\S+)\s(.*) ) {
        set $sanitized_request "$1 $2:<hidden-token>/$3 $4";
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log token_filter;

    location ~* \/file\/bot\d+:(.*) {
        rewrite ^/file\/bot(.*) /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @files;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @api;
    }

    location @files {
        root /var/lib/telegram-bot-api;
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 64 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
    }

    location @api {
        proxy_pass  http://telegram-bot-api;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}```
````

Comment: I'm facing the same!
But that works:

`curl -i http://nginx:81/file/botTOKEN_ID:TOKEN_HASH/documents/file_16.apk`

Did you @NitroRX resolve it ?